# jQuery menu left sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css

#### jQuery

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidr-package-1.2.1/stylesheets/jquery.sidr.dark.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="sidr-package-1.2.1/jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#simple-menu').sidr();
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr">Toggle menu</a>

    <div id="sidr">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Questions

My questions are following:

1. How to hide the slidebar when I click outside of the hyperlink (a tag)?
2. I want to style the list word into orange color. How to write in css?

Comment: #sidr ul li a{ color: orange; } for the list word to be orange?

Comment: yes, i want the word become orange

Comment: Also, I suggest to take a look at JQuery's blur event (http://api.jquery.com/blur/) you can call the sidr(?) function in the blur event

Answer (score 0):

(1) Target every element inside body except a with id="simple-menu"

```
$('body *').not('body a#simple-menu').click(function() {
    // hide sidebar
    $('#sidr').hide();
})
```

(2)

```
#sidr li > a {
    color: orange;
}
```

Comment: would be nice if #sidr is included so it won't affect any other li items in the page.

Comment: anywhere in the body tag.

Comment: @MichaelKuan if you want all the list items in the page to be orange then just remove #sidr and use li a instead.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question you can do the followin:

```
$(body).click(function(){
     $('#simple-menu').sidr();
     // if it has a toggle function the library itself it will work
     // if not you have to give us the js code so we can do the opposite function
})
```

For the second question:

```
#sidr li a{
     color:orange;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) change in jquery.sidr.dark.css file 
    .sidr ul li a, .sidr ul li span

(2) use
    $.sidr('close', 'sidr');